# In TextMate, how do I position the cursor inside a newly generated HTML tag?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I came from the Windows TextMate clone e-texteditor. And in that app, and set to Ruby on Rails bundle while in an `.html.erb` document, if I was to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> (equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> in TextMate), then I get

```
<p></p>
```

with the letter "p" in the first pointed brackets highlighted where I can type any text and the other closing brackets' "p" will change accordingly. All is well in both TextMate and in e-texteditor so far. But in e-texteditor, if I then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the cursor will be moved to the content of these HTML tags like this:

```
<p>|</p>
```

where `|` represents the cursor. Now I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> is supposed to wrap selected text in TextMate, and e-texteditor does that, too! But I find being able to make a pair of HTML tags and tab inside instead of arrow-key myself back in very convenient.

Perhaps there is another shortcut for this?

---

Just in case I am not being crystal clear already: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> (or another shortcut), when pressed, first generates

```
<p></p>
```

with the first 'p' highlighted ready to be changed. Changed or not, when <kbd>Tab</kbd> is then pressed, the cursor should go in between these opening and closing HTML tags.

Comment: This has been annoying me for ages. Would love to find out a way to get around this. The only possible workaround I found is to type the content before, and then wrap it, but you've already mentioned.

Comment: Nik, you are simply using the wrong shortcut, see my edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT*

Something was bugging me with your question: I didn't remember having that problem at all but I somehow forgot most of what I once knew about TextMate (switched to Vim a year ago). I just re-licensed TextMate to play around with TM2 so here is your answer:

You are using the "wrong" shortcut.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> is for **wrapping the currently selected text with opening and closing tags**.

Since you hit this shortcut without a selection you end up with an empty tag. Because it's designed to work with some pre-existing content it's quite logical that it doesn't provide the ability to edit said content further.

The typical use case is when you paste some raw text from a brief and go through it to add proper HTML formatting.

This shortcut inserting an empty HTML tag pair is something of a mirage. Sure it does that but  it's a side effect of not using it properly.

The correct shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd><</kbd> which is for **inserting opening and closing tags optionally using the current word.**

You can use it in two ways:

1. If you have whitespace on the left of the caret, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd><</kbd> to insert `<p></p>` with the first `p` selected. You can either change `p` to something like `h1` and have it mirrored to the closing tag or hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the caret between the tags, like that: `<p>|</p>`.

   Which, I think, is exactly what you want and, actually, what I've always done. Hence my discomfort with your question.
2. If your caret is positioned just after a word, say `span`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd><</kbd> to replace `span` with `<span></span>` with the first `span` selected. You have now the exact same possibilities as with the first method.

*END EDIT*

My TextMate days are gone now so this solution is probably not the best one but it's very easy to put in practice.

Simply create a snippet with the letter `t` as trigger and

```
<${1:tag}>$0</$1>
```

as content.

When it's done you only have to type `t<Tab>p<Tab>` then your content.

Obviously, as it is there is a rather important drawback: if you add attributes they will be mirrored to the end tag.

This can be mitigated by adding an extra tab stop:

```
<${1:tag}${2: }>$0</$1>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just change the Wrap Selection In Tag snippet from

```
<${1:p}>$TM_SELECTED_TEXT</${1/\s.*//}>
```

to

```
<${1:p}>${0:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}</${1/\s.*//}>
```